# Is there something wrong with an abstract value used in trait in scala?

Tags: scala, traits

I have

```
trait Invoker {
  val method: Method
}
```

Intellij IDEA code inspection is warning me that "Abstract value used in trait". Everything compiles fine. Is there something wrong with having an abstract value in a trait? If so, how should I specify that all extenders of the trait must define a method property?

Comment: IntelliJ goes even step further and if you expand the tooltip over this warning you will find: "*Abstract values and variables in trait may cause errors during initialization.*" Sometimes these tooltips are even quoting Scala Lang. Spec.

Comment: If you are comfortable with abstract vals then you can go to Settings / Inspections / Scala / Abstract value in trait and turn down the warning level.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What is meant by this is the following weirdness:

```
trait A {
  val i: String
  def j: String
}

class C extends A {
  println ("val i = " + i)
  println ("def j = " + j)

  val i = "i"
  def j = "j"
}

val c = new C
// prints
// val i = null
// def j = j
```

So, as you can see `i` is initialised to it default value (`null` for `AnyRef`) before it is finally overridden by the constructor in `C`. (`def` declarations are re-referenced immediately.)

To avoid this one would have to put the `val` initialisations to the beginning of the constructor, if possible.

---

*Additional weirdness (and how to solve it) in the following case*

Consider

```
trait A {
  val i: String
  def j: String
}

abstract class D extends A {
  println ("val i = " + i)
  println ("def j = " + j)
}

class C extends D {
  val i = "i"
  def j = "j"
}
val c = new C
// prints
// val i = null
// def j = null
```

Now we seem to be out of luck; it looks as if there is no chance for us to initialise `val i` *and* `def j` before our superclass `D` tries to print them.
In order to solve this problem, we must use *Early definitions* (§5.1.6 [Scala reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)):

```
class C extends {
  val i = "i"
  def j = "j"
} with D

val c = new C
// prints
// val i = i
// def j = j
```

And it works!

Comment: Rather late comment, but since this is still being linked: the problem is _not_ the abstract `val`, but the implementation in `C`. If you change `i` in `A` to `def`, you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 6):

There are plenty of good reasons to use an abstract val in a trait. Unfortunately, IntelliJ IDEA does not distinguish those and simply warns against their use universally. In practice, this means that IntelliJ IDEA warnings are ignored.

Comment: But the full warning message is fair. And after all it's a warning not a error.

Comment: @pedrofurla: unavoidable warnings in correct code are an annoyance to good programmers, but a broken window invitation for weaker programmers to leave real problems in their code. It shouldn't be a warning.  Tony is right that is far too opinionated for an IDE to be emitting warnings like this. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-3651 for an issue to vote to fix this.

Comment: Good programmers have to know how to interpret warnings. Errors in correct programs are an annoyance.

Comment: I believe doing this backtrack in your head while you have other problems to tackle is a bit tedious. Supposingly we use scala because we favor simplicity. I will choose to enable this warning.