# IntelliJ warning : "abstract value used in trait may cause errors during initialization" - what's the problem with LAZY abstract val-s?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, initialization, traits, cake-pattern

IntelliJ gives me the warning that "abstract value in trait may cause errors during initialization" - as shown in the picture below.

- What does this mean ?
- Should I take this warning seriously ?
- Should I use `def`-s instead of `lazy val`-s ?
- Are they not the same in this case ? Since we are talking here about dependency injection, which creates a static - possibly cyclical - object graph.
- But ! because the `lazy` modifier is there, it does not matter if the graph is cyclical or not. Right ?
- The values themselves will simply behave as  they were a memoized function right ?
- Since we are talking about references here (in a static object graph) where references are directed edges and objects are nodes, **what's the problem here** ?
- Could you please give an example where using `lazy val`-s instead of `def`-s can cause problems during initialization ?

Thank you for reading :)

The whole codebase is on github.

[This](https://github.com/jhegedus42/irie/blob/ccb516f9e2d04008488fd8166c1c98c088e812e5/modules/server/src/main/scala/app/server/httpServer/routes/post/routeLogicImpl/UpdateRL.scala#L60) is the particular line that is problematic (on github).

I also copy paste the problematic code here:

```
trait EntityMarshallers[V<:EntityValue[V]]{
  implicit lazy val decoderEntityV:    Decoder[Entity[V]]
  implicit lazy val encoderEntityV:    Encoder[Entity[V]]
  implicit lazy val _encoderV:         Encoder[V]
  implicit lazy val classTag:          ClassTag[V]

}
```

This is the IntelliJ warning :

[image]

Comment: If you try to compile your code you'll see that you get compile error "lazy values may not be abstract".

Comment: Try to make them `implicit def`.

Comment: Regarding initialisation warning see [Why is my abstract or overridden val null?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html) and [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7846119/5205022).

Comment: @MarioGalic but strangely on this article one solution for that are `lazy val`s